# Unable to run selenium test inside docker container using TeamCity

Tags: docker, selenium, maven, teamcity, google-chrome-headless

I am having trouble running test inside a docker container in TeamCity. The project is a test project which includes: openjdk, maven, selenium, chrome (headless). Below command works locally:

```
cd to/my/src/code
mvn clean
mvn test
```

However, when I try to run the same command using TC build step which uses below dockerfile to run all the test I get error.

DockerFile:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install Chocolatey
RUN write-host "*********** Install Chocolatey"
ARG chocolateyVersion='0.10.11'
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install googlechrome
RUN write-host "*********** Install googlechrome"
RUN choco install googlechrome -y

# Install openjdk
RUN write-host "*********** Install openjdk"
RUN choco install openjdk --version=18.0.1.1 -y

# Install maven
RUN write-host "*********** Install maven"
RUN choco install maven --version=3.8.6 -y

# Verify installation
RUN java --version
RUN mvn −version
```

Error from TeamCity:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.id: LoginName' (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at com.mycompany.pages.PublishAccountPage.loginFunctionForJCR(PublishAccountPage.java:44)
    at com.mycompany.tests.SampleTest.Sample(SampleTest.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#LoginName"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.134)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

TC build step:
[image]

Comment: It's a generic _TimeoutException_ for the visibility of Proxy element `By.id: LoginName`. Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium - Are you hinting towards increasing timeout? I can do that. Wonder why it works locally on my box and also for other tester but not inside container? It is not able to detect anything on the page, not even a page title

Comment: Need to see the HTML and your code. `mvn clean test` is just the maven command to kickoff the test execution.